# Clear content with button

Tags: javascript, html

I am able to save user data from input field into paragraph, but I want to delete the contents of the paragraph with a click of button.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="enter">
<br>
<button id="btn" onclick="fn()">click</button>
<div>
    <p id="result"></p>
</div>
<button onclick="clear()">clear</button>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function fn(){
    var Name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML += '<br>' + Name;
}
function clear(){
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "";
}
```

Comment: OK what is the issue you are facing.. What is not working out. please elaborate

Comment: and please, if you can, include a snippet

Comment: Too many copycats are there, please check my answer (first).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the problem here is the `clear()` function name, it's not a reserved word, but it will invoke `document.clear` in the first place, so try any other name for your function:

```js
function fn(){
    var Name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML += '<br>' + Name;
}
function clearContent(){
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = '';
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="enter">
<br>
<button id="btn" onclick="fn()">click</button>
<div>
    <p id="result"></p>
</div>
<button onclick="clearContent()">clear</button>
```

**Update**

To remove the inserted data one by one, you need to create an event listener for each created element, a simple implementation would be (remove element on click):

```js
function fn() {
  var Name = document.getElementById('name').value;

  var paragraph = document.createElement('p');
  paragraph.innerHTML = Name + ' (X)';

  paragraph.onclick = function(el) {
    el.target.remove();
    return false;
  };

  document.getElementById('result').appendChild(paragraph);
}

function clearContent(){
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = '';
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="enter">
<br>
<button id="btn" onclick="fn()">click</button>
<div>
  <p id="result"></p>
</div>
<button onclick="clearContent()">clear</button>
```

Comment: what if I want to clear the content entered in paragraph one by one?

Comment: You have to insert your new data into a paragraph that has a class, and will need a button for each to remove the current paragraph.

Comment: May I know why I got a downvote, how could I improve my answer?

Answer (score 4):

It seems `clear` will call `document.clear`. Change the function name to something else

```js
let dom = document.getElementById('result');

function fn() {
  var Name = document.getElementById('name').value;
  dom.innerHTML += '<br>' + Name;
}

function clearVal() {
  dom.innerHTML = "";
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="enter">
<br>
<button id="btn" onclick="fn()">click</button>
<div>
  <p id="result"></p>
</div>
<button onclick="clearVal()">clear</button>
```

Comment: what if I want to clear the content entered in paragraph one by one?

Answer (score 3):

`clear` method of the window object will be called. Therefore, you are not able to see the changes. Rename your function except `clear`

In order to reset the `input`, you can use `document.getElementById('name').reset()`.

```js
var randkey=0;
function fn(){
  var Name = document.getElementById('name').value;
  randKey = Math.floor(Math.random()*999);
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML +=  '<div id='+randKey+'>' + Name +'<br><button onclick=cleardd('+randKey+')>clear</button></div>';
  
}
function cleardd(randKey){
  document.getElementById(randKey).remove();
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="enter">
<br>
<button id="btn" onclick="fn()">click</button>
<div id="result">
</div>
```

Comment: what if I want to clear the content entered in paragraph one by one?

Comment: i have updated my answer, have a look. @pratteekshaurya

Comment: Hey @pratteekshaurya, in the accepted answer, when you click on the paragraph also it will be deleted. Its better to maintain a unique id to each paragraph and delete by button.

Answer (score 2):

Please use any name other than clear. I think it is a keyword.

```js
function fn(){
    var Name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML += '<br>' + Name;
}
function clearText(){
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = '';
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="enter">
<br>
<button id="btn" onclick="fn()">click</button>
<div>
    <p id="result"></p>
</div>
<button onclick="clearText()">clear</button>
```

Comment: what if I want to clear the content entered in paragraph one by one?